# Coordinate Transformation using a Matrix

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Consider two inertial and resting frames $K$ and $G$. The only difference between the two frames is that the axes of $G$ has been rotated with $\theta$ with respect to $K$. $G$ is *not* constantly rotating, the axes are fixed in space.

For a vector $\vec r\in\mathbb{R}^3$, we can express it in $K$ frame as:
$$ \vec r=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^k\ \vec e_i^k,$$ where $\vec e_i^k$ are the unit vectors in each direction in $K$ frame.
We can express $\vec r$ in $G$ frame as: $$\vec r=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^g\ \vec e_i^g$$ too. We know that we can express the rotation of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrix, which we will denote here as $R$, such that: $$\forall i : \ \vec e_i^g =R\ \vec e_i^k$$

Thus, we find the relationship:
$$\vec r=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^k\ \vec e_i^k=\displaystyle\sum x_i^g\ \vec e_i^g\ =\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^g\ R\vec e_i^k\stackrel{x_i^k\ \text{is a scalar}}= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^3 Rx_i^g\ \vec e_i^k$$

From this we see: $$\forall i: \ \ R\ x_i^g=x_i^k$$

But the left side is a matrix, whereas the right side is a scalar, how is that possible? Where have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of the linear operator $R$ on a basis vector is
$$
R [{\bf e}_k]= {\bf e}_j {R^j}_k,
$$
where the array of numbers ${R^j}_k$ is a matrix:
$$
\left[\matrix{{R^1}_1, & {R^1}_2& \ldots \cr {R^2}_1, & {R^2}_2& \ldots\cr \vdots& \vdots& \ddots}\right].
$$
Y0u seem to be confusing the abstract operator with its basis-dependent matrix. Your last equation should be something like
$$
{R^j}_k {x'}^k= x^j
$$

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that!